# Broadcast a file on wifi local network with Mobile

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi

I need to broadcast a file on a wifi local network with phone Android. The scenario like this: my mobile send a file to the modem, so the modem can broadcast this file to the another mobiles in the same network. I must explain like this because someone may think about P2P (what I don't want here).

I know that the developer of Android usually work on the layer application. So, I wonder if it exist API or the library or they way to do the execution on the deeper layer (layer TCP and layer IP).

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am making a couple of assumptions,
1. That by broadcast a file, you mean transfer a file.
2. By connecting to a modem you meant connecting to a WiFi network.

The tutorial given [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) on Network Service Discovery will help you with advertising a service and connecting to one (even retrieving the info of the host of the service).

In the 'onServiceFound' listener, hold on to the host's details till you listen to an 'onServiceLost' from that host.
Using the host's details you can identify and also open a socket connection, over which you can transfer the file.